# How to disable motion blur in unity HDRP

Tags: unity, rendering, post-processing

This is probably a really simple question, but I just started trying to use Unity's HDRP, and was wondering if there was a way to remove the intense motion blur when moving the mouse.

Basically, is this what is needed to render the scene, or is it something that you can change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you can disable it!**

Find a GameObject with a Post Process Volume attached (It will be probably be named "PostProcess" by default.)
There in the Post Process script, scroll and look for "Motion Blur", set its `Intensity` to 0.